# Hide decimal on hompage, category and product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

0
down vote
favorite
I have a little problem with calculating the taxes on woocommerce. The problem is that if I have 2 decimal set from woocommerce, and the vat number is 19 for romania, at the total of an order I found another 0.01 RON in plus.

If I have 3 decimal set, or 4, the total is OK, is any posibilitie to hide decimal from all over the website except the order and the invoice?

[image]

I'm mentioning that I used this code to hide the decimal, but it's working only for the homepage, category and product page.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', '__return_true' );
```